# What does "even thus" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, literature

Working through another C.A. Smith's story, I fail to understand what "even thus" mean. Not even Googling could answer the question because most sources just state the examples with no hints of the meaning.

> Flowers of many hues had been strewn upon the bier, and their
> fragrance filled the air with a drowsy languor, with an anodyne that
> seemed to drug my heart and brain. Such flowers had been cast on the
> bier of Mariel; and **even thus**, at her funeral, I had been overcome by
> a momentary dulling of the senses because of their perfume.

The whole paragraph is not completely clear because the second sentence seems to just repeat what is in the first one, but maybe the "even thus" phrase will - once I understand it - change it?

Comment: Related, from another piece of literature and another SE site: [What does “even so did I” mean?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/15387/17)

Answer (score 1):

It means

> ***Despite*** the context of the funeral, I still let myself delight in the fragrance of those flowers.

So the slight paradox there is that the author allowed himself to delight in something that is supposed to be sorrowful.

(even thus = even in such a situation)

Edit: My answer is not correct as I was kindly helped to understand. So please read the comments to this answer to find out the correct meaning of ***even thus***.

Comment: He seems to be referring to two different funerals. At the present one, the scent of flowers intoxicates him _in the same way as_ the flowers at Mariel's funeral had done.

Comment: @KateBunting This is an interesting point because the plot of the story is about a man who is trying to escape memories of his lover, lady Mariel, only to end up in a city that apparently prepares funeral rites for (another?) lady Mariel. So he could be remembering the funeral of "his" Mariel but in this paragraph I am not sure it is the case :/

Comment: @KateB: yes, well spotted. But I think this doesn't influence the meaning of _**even thus**_ too much. It is connected to _her funeral_.

Comment: @fev Kate is correct here. This is an older meaning of 'even', which is very frequently found in the Bible (and confuses people not familiar with it). It is also familiar to anyone who speaks German, because *eben* is used with this older meaning but not with the newer English meaning.

Comment: @legatrix: I see. So how would explain 'even thus' then? What would you replace it with?

Comment: "just as", "exactly as", or Kate's "in the same way as".

Comment: Sorry, that syntax isn't quite right for the quote: rather, "in just that way", "exactly thus", etc.

Comment: Typical Biblical example: "Blessed be the Lord, who daily loadeth us with benefits, even the God of our salvation."

Comment: @legatrix: Yes, you are right. Now I understand it! I am glad I ventured to answer, I would have remained with the wrong understanding.

Comment: @fev Will you then change your answer?

Comment: @JohnV: I was wondering if this would not confuse more the readers, because then all the comments will become irrelevant. I thought to leave it as it is for them to understand the progress of my _seeing the light_  :)  ! Is that ok?

Comment: @fev Indeed, that makes sense. But I guess then I cannot accept that, even though it did lead to the correct understanding, in the end :)

Comment: @JohnV: I have added a explanation.